# Quando escrevo no input o texto começa a aparecer no meio em vez do começo

Tags: html, css

Sou bem iniciante ainda no html/css e não achei resposta em nenhum lugar, mas então, no input eu coloquei um css para aumentar o tamanho da "box" etc, mas quando escrevo aparece o "|" de começar a escrever em uma posição estranha, queria q começasse no começo.

CSS/HTML:

```css
aside {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: white;
    border: 2px #438df2 solid;
    float: left;
    height: 75.56%
}

aside p {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    margin: 15px;
}

.label1, .label2 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 15px;
}

#email {
    padding: 0px 35px 10px 50px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#email2 {
    padding: 0px 60px 120px 60px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
  <aside>
     <p>Interested in my work? Send me a message!</p>
     
      <label for="email" class="label1">Insert your email here:</label>
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="Email" class="input1"></p>
        
        <label for="text" class="label2">Insert your message here:</label>
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="email2" name="Text" class="input1"></p>
        
        <button>Send</button>
        
  </aside>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É por causa dos paddings:

```
#email {
    padding: 0px 35px 10px 50px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#email2 {
    padding: 0px 60px 120px 60px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Você pode trocar por width e height:

```css
aside {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: white;
    border: 2px #438df2 solid;
    float: left;
    height: 75.56%
}

aside p {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    margin: 15px;
}

.label1, .label2 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 15px;
}

#email {
    width: 260px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#email2 {
    width: 295px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
  <aside>
     <p>Interested in my work? Send me a message!</p>
     
      <label for="email" class="label1">Insert your email here:</label>
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="Email" class="input1"></p>
        
        <label for="text" class="label2">Insert your message here:</label>
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="email2" name="Text" class="input1"></p>
        
        <button>Send</button>
        
  </aside>
```

O segundo input ficou bem grande, acho que o que você quer é um textarea talvez, veja assim:

```css
aside {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: white;
    border: 2px #438df2 solid;
    float: left;
    height: 75.56%
}

aside p {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    margin: 15px;
}

.label1, .label2 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 15px;
}

#email {
    width: 260px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#email2 {
    width: 295px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
  <aside>
     <p>Interested in my work? Send me a message!</p>
     
      <label for="email" class="label1">Insert your email here:</label>
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="Email" class="input1"></p>
        
        <label for="text" class="label2">Insert your message here:</label>
      <p>
        <textarea id="email2" name="Text" class="input1"></textarea></p>
        
        <button>Send</button>
        
  </aside>
```

Comment: Ahh era só isso então nossa, mas ao invés de usar esse textarea eu posso modificar o width e height não? tipo diminuir o height do segundo input etc, ou esses px que vc colocou foi por algum propósito?

Comment: @PatrickPassarella eu fiz para ficar identico ao teu, mas o ponteiro não ficar no meio. Você pode alterar `width: <valor>px;` e `height: <valor>px;` a vontade.

Comment: Okay, muito obrigado, resolveu

Comment: @PatrickPassarella veja que o textarea diferente do input, aceita várias linhas. Se a resposta resolveu o problema marque-a como correta por favor. [**Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635)